# Trying to "import" code from one html document to another with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I swear I've copied and pasted 100 different things that should work, but nothing is working.

I have my main html document, test.html:

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header></header>
  <div class='content'>some content</div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Another html document, test2.html:

```html
<p>this should show up if it works</p>
```

And a javascript document, script.js:

```js
$(function() {
  $("header").load("test2.html");
});
```

My end goal is to get a navbar.html document that can be referenced via jquery by multiple different html documents. Here, I'm trying to do a verrrrrrry simple test to get the .load() function to work.

When I load test.html, I expect to see the text from both test.html and test2.html, but I'm not seeing the text from test2.html. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use your browser's dev-tools (usually opened by hitting F12) to debug the problem. There's probably an error being reported that will help you find a solution

Comment: Open the browser's console, check what the error messages are. If there are no error messages, next check the network tab and confirm that the Ajax request is completed and it gets the correct content.

Comment: Thank you both - I'm so new to this I had no idea I could check the browser console (had to google how to do that lol). I am getting an error message - looking into it now.

Comment: If you're still struggling with it, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64921778/edit) to include the error details

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of request, you need to be running on a server as you will get an CORS (Cross Origin Ressource Sharing) if running the file directly from your html file. You could use Live Server on Visual Studio code or directly on an apache server to run your perticular code.

You can also see this link if my first answer doesn't work https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9